# How to calculate a definite integral with a variable as an endpoint and get its derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

$$F(x) = \int_{{3}}^{x^2} \frac{t^{{5}} + \sin(t)}{t^{{5}}} dt$$
$$Find\:F'(x)$$
I've been trying to think about how to do this question for hours and trying many different things. I would imagine there is a way to do it without taking the antiderivative as it seems a really complex task. If someone could point me in the right direction on this that would be great.

Comment: See the [first part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: You are not asked to compute the integral.

Comment: @soupless thanks for the tip, that's all that I needed, was able to look up some tutorials from there. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with the first part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
$$f(t)=\frac{t^5+sin(t)}{t^5}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}[F(x^2)-F(3)]$$
$$f(x^2)(2x)-0$$
$$\frac{x^{10} + sin(x^2)}{x^{10}} \cdot 2x$$

Comment: After some time, you may consider accepting your answer.